# Partial Border around icons & elements on transparent background

Tags: css, icons

How can I create a resizeable (or even set widths ) of borders around icons and other elements on the page like shown below, against a transparent background?

[image: Element 1]

[image: Element 2 and 3]

```
------[element]------
```

best line of thinking is currently

```
<div class="outer"> Border left / right
  outer:before - Border top/ bottom; width:10%
    Element
  outer:after- Border top/ bottom; width:10%
</div>
```

But how do i incorporate the horizontal lines ether side encompassing the entire middle section

Comment: Border style almost similar to this can be found here http://css-shapes.xyz/border-styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly I like to go full CSS without using images of any sort, I would use 2 extra div elements on the left and right side of the icon, which acts as the "brackets"

```
<div class="icon-container">
    <div class="icon-border icon-border-left"></div>
    <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i> <!-- or your central element -->
    <div class="icon-border icon-border-right"></div>
</div>
```

I would style the brackets in a conventional way like this:

```
.icon-container .icon-border {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Then apply a pseudo element to the brackets to create the "line", positioned absolutely with a really long width.

```
.icon-container .icon-border:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    width: 2048px;
    background: black;
}
```

And finally, apply all the exceptions to move the brackets closer to the icon, to give the illusion it is wrapping it up and then give left and right to the pseudo classes in order to draw a line from the end of the bracket until the end of the screen:

```
.icon-container .icon-border.icon-border-left {
    border-right-width: 0px;
    margin-right: -21px;
}
.icon-container .icon-border.icon-border-left:before {
    right: 100%;
}
.icon-container .icon-border.icon-border-right {
    border-left-width: 0px;
    margin-left: -21px;
}
.icon-container .icon-border.icon-border-right:before {
    left: 100%;
}
```

Last crucial thing, your main icon container must have `overflow: hidden` otherwise your lines will span across the entire screen, probably going out the container and going out your body resulting in a very awful horizontal scrollbar.

**Demo**: http://codepen.io/luigimannoni/pen/epPBXJ

Comment: Thanks, this is the best answer because it allows the elements to be used responsively, just set the width on .icon-container .icon-border:before {} to be the longest you could ever use (200em? ) and then it becomes a responsive element within a responsive container

Answer (score 5):

Let me add another way. I don't use any extra divs in the html. Only a wrapper and a span.

The span gets the class bracketed to draw the brackets. I use a linear gradient as the border. In this example I use a simple black-transparent-black gradient but of course you can use a more complex gradient.

I then use two pseudo-elements on the wrapper div to draw the horizontal lines. Here too you can get a lot more fancy than a simple black border.

```css
body {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffc, #ccf);
}
.bracketed{
 padding: 15px 20px;
 border: 1px solid;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, black 29%, transparent 30%, transparent 70%, black 71%, black 100%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
}
.bordered {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 20px;
 display: flex;
}
.bordered::before, .bordered::after{
 content: "";
 flex: 1;
 align-self: center;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-width: 1px 0px 0px;
 height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered"><span class="bracketed">A</span></div>
```

If you want to use this on an image all you need in the html is

```
<div class="bordered"><img /></div>
```

See an example with a font-awesome icon on [codepen](http://codepen.io/woestijnrog/pen/jbeyJV).

Comment: Thanks, all the examples on this page are brilliant - due to ie 8/9/10 compatibility on border-image, not sure its best to use this one for the moment

Comment: I like this one, very elegant and doesn't use lots of markup, aside the flex container which probably won't work on old browsers I would defo go for this one if I were developing a ng website.

Answer (score 0):

For this horizontal line you may use the background-image property with repeat-x and position left center. And for these brackets you can take :before and :after pseudo classes with DIV elements positioned absolutely on both sides of your button element taking 100% height and 20px width. This is just one of few solutions which came to my mind first :)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="left"></div>
       <button>Test</button>
   <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<style>
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

button {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -10px 0 0;
}

.left::before {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  right: 30px;
}

.left::after {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 30px;
  content: "";
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.right {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
}

.right::before {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  left: 30px;
}

.right::after {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-right: 1px solid #333         
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 30px;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
```

http://codepen.io/robotslater/pen/LpgxGe

Comment: Thanks, all the examples on this page are brilliant